# Is there any difference between these statements?

Tags: java, performance, memory, resources, method-call

Is there any difference between:

```
String x = getString();
doSomething(x);
```

vs.

```
doSomething(getString());
```

Resources and performance wise, Especially is it's done within a loop for tens, hundreds or thousands of times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has the same overhead. Local variables are just there to make your life easier. At the VM level they don't necessarily exist and certainly not anymore when machine code is run.

So what you need to worry about here is `getString()`, whether it is potentially expensive. `x` has very likely no effect at all.

Comment: What's this "separate storage" you're talking about in the CLR? It's the first I've heard of it - do you have a link to some documentation?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok, maybe it's just a IL detail. I was referring to `.local` and instructions like `stloc` and  `ldloc`. Maybe I understood something differently. I never formally learned that stuff; only dabbled a bit in it. I removed that statement, though, as it's unlikely that I am correct if you don't know about it ;-)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I now read that far in the [CLR spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) (p. 88f): There is an array of local variables that is part of the method state. So creating a local or not creating it can indeed make a difference. I just skimmed the part, though, maybe I'm still overlooking something.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first begin by saying that your overriding goal should almost always be to maintain code readability.  Your compiler is almost always better at trivial optimizations than you are.  Trust it!

In response to your specific example: the bytecode generated for each example IS different.  It didn't appear to make much difference though, because there wasn't a statistically significant or even consistent difference between the two approaches in a loop over Integer.MAX_VALUE iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both would be the same at compile time, the first may become more code readable in some cases though.

Answer (score 0):

Both the statements are same. only difference is that in first approach you have used a local variable X which can be avoided using second syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That largely depends on the use-case.  Are you going to make repeated calls to doSomething using that exact String?  Then using the local variable is a bit more efficient. However, if it's a single call or multiple calls with different Strings, it makes no difference.